# Issue with pandas.replace not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been trying to create a script that opens a csv file, and replaces a specific character for another:
The rows on the csv are like this: `C9JLR9,1..100,150..200,220..230`
And I'm trying to `replace` every `".."` by a `blank space` with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd  
table = pd.read_excel(r""D:\Tesina\Proteoma Humano\Tablas\uno - copia.csv",error_bad_lines=False)
table = table["SEQ"].replace(".."," ")
```

But, when i either print the table or save it to another csv file, the output still has all  the "..".

I'm surely missing something obvious!
I'm also trying to come up with a way that sums the delta of the numbers (skipping the 1, that is) so I have a row that holds the value of, in the case of the example, 160, but I don't know how to do it.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need replace substrings `..` first escape it because `.` is special regex character and then pass to [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or add parameter `regex=True` to [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
table = pd.DataFrame({'SEQ':['1..100','150..200','220..230']})

table["SEQ"] = table["SEQ"].str.replace("\.\."," ")
#alternative
#table["SEQ"] = table["SEQ"].replace("\.\."," ", regex=True)
print (table)
       SEQ
0    1 100
1  150 200
2  220 230
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
table["SEQ"] = table["SEQ"].str.replace(".."," ")
```

instead of

```
table = table["SEQ"].replace(".."," ")
```